# Mage::dispatchEvent resetting the old values

Tags: magento

Im using "admin_permissions_role_prepare_save" event to update role details. The update is happening. The new values has been stored. But after updating, rolecontrollers saveRoleAction's dispatch event restores to the old values.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'admin_permissions_role_prepare_save',
                array('object' => $role, 'request' => $this->getRequest())
            );
```

This request data has old values. How do I update the request data to have new values?

Edit:
Here is my observer.

```
public function saveStoreInformation($observer) { 
        $role_id =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('role_id');
        $store_ids_array = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('gws_store_groups');
        $store_ids = implode(',',$store_ids_array);
        if(in_array(0,$store_ids_array))
        { $gws_is_all = 1; } else {$gws_is_all = 0;}
        //$model = Mage::getModel('admin/role');

        if($role_id) {
            $data = array('gws_is_all'=>$gws_is_all,'gws_store_groups'=>"$store_ids");
            $model = Mage::getModel('admin/role')->setData($data);
            try {
                    $model->setId($role_id)
                          ->save();
                    echo "Data updated successfully.";
                } catch (Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }        
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you *dispatch* this event on your own? Or if not, what is your actual observer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using observers as intended. What you should do is change the provided object:

```
$observer->getObject()->setData(...);
```

this results in the following process:

- event gets dispatched with parameter `$role`
- you change `$role` in your observer
- `$role` gets saved

whereas your current solution does the following:

- event gets dispatched with parameter `$role`
- you ignore the parameter, load the role by yourself and save it
- the **unchanged** `$role` object gets saved and overwrites your own changes